# What rate of decline in COVID cases is suggested by presidential guidelines?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, covid-19

So I was able to get the [Guidelines for Opening America](https://assets.documentcloud.org/documents/6840663/Governmentpacket.pdf) this afternoon, but was unable to watch the press briefing where they were discussed. 
One of the key criteria for a state or region to met before lifting restrictions is that there be a "downward trajectory of documented cases within a 14 day period". (BTW, I've assumed that they mean **new** cases). However there was no guidance relative to the steepness of that trajectory.

I have tried to find any media coverage (Google, news services etc) that might have a report on what occurs to me as an obvious question that might have been asked - what is the suggested negative slope of the qualifying trajectory.

Do any of our SE.politics Participants know if that was asked or what the answer might have been.

Comment: If you have an hour, you can [watch the briefing on youtube](https://youtu.be/v_2F0a9sjko?t=6164) yourself and see what they said.

Comment: so much for _measurable_ progress...

Comment: And what I was predicting about Trump scapegoating governors (Bolsonaro style)... came true only one day later https://edition.cnn.com/2020/04/18/opinions/trump-is-playing-with-fire-ghitis/index.html

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there isn't one. Here's the slide used in the [press conference](https://youtu.be/v_2F0a9sjko?t=7628):

[image]